# Copying a specific string from a website

Tags: android

As an aviation lover, I'm trying to build up an Android App to get METAR/TAF. The main goal of one of the project activities is to go to https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/, and read the METAR/TAF (METHEOROLOGICAL REPORTS) of the airport the user chooses.

As a draft project I have the following xml (read the info from webpage and pasting it into a textViwe):

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    try{

        HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost poste = new HttpPost("https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/?station_ids=LELL&std_trans=standard&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&chk_tafs=on&submitmet=Submit");


        HttpResponse respuesta = cliente.execute(poste);


        HttpEntity entidad=respuesta.getEntity();


        InputStream mensaje=entidad.getContent();


        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        String linea;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mensaje,"UTF-8"));



        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){

            sb.append(linea);
            sb.append("\n");

        }

        tv.setText(sb.toString());

        mensaje.close();
```

The main thing is, I read the whole information and get the following text*, but I just want to display the lines (METAR in red , TAF in blue):

[image]

Any Idea?

I've tried many codes in this website, even tried to get to the webpage with a WebView , but I'd rather display the metheorological information as a text in TextView.

Thanks in advance,

SERGI

Comment: Use any HTML parsing library?

Comment: consider up-voting helpful answers and accepting your own, if that is indeed the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) with the following to access the text you want

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/?station_ids=LELL&std_trans=standard&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&chk_tafs=on&submitmet=Submit").get();
Elements fontTags = content.getElementsByTag("font");
for (Element fontTag : fontTags) {
     String fontTagText = fontTag.text();
}
```

Comment: fontTagText = fontTagText.text();  That part gives me error type: incompatible types...

Comment: I made a typo. It should be `String fontTagText = fontTag.text();`

Comment: String frase =fontTag.text();--can't resolve method fonTag.text()...@Radu lonescu

Comment: You can edit it in my answer to be used if others find the post later

Answer (score 1):

Final code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/?station_ids=LELL&std_trans=standard&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&chk_tafs=on&submitmet=Submit").get();

Elements fontTags = doc.getElementsByTag("font");
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element fontTag : fontTags){
    String frase =fontTags.text();
    TextView hola=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    hola.setText(frase);
}
```